# Why dont kill the alarm manager in android?

Tags: android

I'm beginner in android,and simple run the alarm manager in `mainActivity` with this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(testSendWithFood.this, AlarmReciever.class);
                        intent.putExtra("key", "Alert");
                        //PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
                        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, intent, 0);
                        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 10, 40 * 1000, pendingIntent);
```

and i want in another activity kill that alarm manager with this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReciever.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 1253, intent, 0);
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

but so alarm manager not kill!,why?thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pending intent has to be the same. So if you change the intent id to 1253 when you create the intent and then use the same to cancel the pending intent so change

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),0, intent, 0);
```

To

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 1253, intent, 0);
```

Comment: There we are :) give that a go

Comment: it's work my friend thanks for help me,but what is 1253? this id of intent?